# Unity: TopDown view - GameObject does not rotate toward mousepos

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse-position

I've been doing some research on why my player(GameObject) is does not rotate toward my mouse position in my TopDown 3D game and I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code, so im making this post. The problem thats I have is that only the GameObject of my player (in my case, a capsule) rotate toward my mouse position but the axis of my player stays the same. In other word, I can't rotate the axis of my player, to face my mouse position, but I can rotate the GameObject of my player to face my mouse position. Its really hard to explain and this never happened to me before. Question is how can I rotate the axis of my player to face my mouse position. Keep in mind that my game is a top down view.

Here is the code im using for my playerMouvment and for my mouseLook:

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 6;

    Rigidbody rb;
    Camera viewCamera;
    Vector3 velocity;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        viewCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = viewCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, viewCamera.transform.position.y));
        transform.LookAt(mousePos + Vector3.up * transform.position.y);
        velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * moveSpeed;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Again I tried and look for any error in my code and I can't find anything that cause this weird situation and so if anyone can help me find a better way to write this code and solve my problem it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly everything is fine with your game and the player is turning as it should, but only in the editor that the axis of the player (red, green and blue arrows) don't turn with the player?

If this is the problem it might be that you are using global space handle instead of local space. Clicking the icon I highlighted in the image should do the trick.

[image: trick]

Comment: yep, that fixed it, I cant belive I didnt think of that lol, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Use this code instead of LookAt() function

```
Vector2 direction = mousePos.position - player.transform.position;
player.transform.right /* Maybe you need Up or -Up or -right */ = direction;
```

#### This would work too in some cases

```
Vector2 direction = new Vector2
(
mousePos.position.x - player.transform.position.x,
mousePos.positoin.y - player.transform.position.y
)

player.transform.right /* Maybe you need Up or -Up or -right */ = direction;
```